# Select from 2 table SQL WHERE Clause by ID

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have 2 tables in MySQL, in both of these tables I have merchant_id, merchant, branch and some another fields, the name of one table is merchant and another table is product.

tbl_merchant :

```
    id   |  merchant_id  |   merchant_name    |    branch      |   ...
   ------+---------------+--------------------+----------------+
    1    | 1001          |  McDonalds         |  branch 1 mcd  |   ...
    2    | 2002          |  KFC               |  branch 1 kfc  |   ...
```

tbl_product :

```
    id   |  product_id   |  product_name   |  price  | merchant_id
   ------+---------------+-----------------+---------+-------------
    1    | 100101        |  Chicken        | 10      | 1001
    2    | 100102        |  Potato         | 5       | 1001
    3    | 100101        |  Burger         | 10      | 2002
    4    | 100102        |  Fish Fillet    | 10      | 2002
```

I want to know how can to show merchant_name, branch from both tables using SQL WHERE Clause by product_id = 100101 and merchant_id = 1001 ?

Like this :

```
   Result :
    id   |  merchant   |  branch        |  product_name | price
   ------+-------------+----------------+---------------+-------
    1    | McDonalds   |  branch 1 mcd  |  Chicken      | 10
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from marchant join product on marchant.id=product.merchant_id where merchant_id = 1001
```

This statement will join both tables together where the primary key form merchant is equals the merchant_id in product.

Comment: Ahem, `where and`? I think you're missing something in between these two keywords.

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for OP and other readers.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll show you the query, then I'll explain each part line by line to help you understand:

```
SELECT
   merchant_name, branch
FROM
   tbl_merchant INNER JOIN tbl_product ON (tbl_product.merchant_id = tbl_merchant.merchant_id)
WHERE
   product_id = 100101 AND merchant_id = 1001
```

Alright, so if we look at the first part following the select, it should be clear that the two columns that will be printed out are merchant_name and branch. Based on your output, you can print out any field from either table just by adding its name to the list. If the field has the same name in both tables, then you need to qualify it like this:

```
SELECT
  tbl_merchant.id, tbl_product.id
FROM
  tbl_merchant INNER JOIN tbl_product USING(merchant_id)
```

The tricky part of this query is the line that joins the two tables together. Essentially what you have as of now is two tables that are linked together by a merchant id, which makes sense because 1 merchant can have many products (i.e. a 1 to many relationship). I'm assuming that the merchant ID is unique. The join then pairs together all the rows that have the same merchant_id (which is unique in one of the tables and therefore guaranteed to be correct). More specially you can think of it as a qualified cross product where each tuple from tbl_product is joined with each tuple from tbl_merchant and then qualified based on the condition tbl_product.merchant_id = tbl_merchant.merchant_id.

The last part of the query (WHERE clause) simply eliminates rows based on the conditions provided.

Comment: please help..  If I have merchant_id and product_id inside tbl_transaction, how to showing merchant_name and product_name using Where Clause only by customer_id, I try to modified your code, but i get some error like alias. thank you

Comment: and now I'm full understand what you mean to unique, I create syntax and working if unique for product_id in every merchant_id : "SELECT * from tbl_transaction Inner Join tbl_merchant On tbl_transaction.merchant_id = tbl_merchant.merchant_id Inner Join tbl_product On tbl_transaction.product_id = tbl_product.product_id where cust_id = 001"  but if I have same product id on another merchant id I getting duplicate result. possible or not if i want to select category_id. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The query for this is:

SELECT      merchant_name, branch
FROM
   tbl_merchant
 INNER JOIN
 tbl_product
 ON (tbl_product.merchant_id = tbl_merchant.merchant_id)
WHERE
   product_id = 100101 AND merchant_id = 1001

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT merchants.id, merchants.merchant_id, merchants.branch, products.product_name, products.price 
FROM merchants 
INNER JOIN products ON products.merchant_id = merchants.merchant_id 
WHERE merchants.merchant_id = 1001 AND products.product_id = 100101
```

you can use JOIN to solve this type of query

there are some good article to learn more about JOIN with visula explanation::

1) http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ "A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins"

2) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins "Visual Representation of SQL Joins"

Comment: Thank you for reference site